# Google Chrome doesn't load website's correct Google Fonts and 'fonts.google.com' itself doesn't show any fonts. How to fix this?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, chromium

**Software Information:**

- Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)
  installed using official .deb from Google.
- Ubuntu 19.04 With Gnome
    3.32

**What I tested:** 
Removed all extensions, cleared history and cookies and reset settings, purged and reinstalled Google Chrome, installed Chromium. But problem persists.

**Screenshots:**

**fonts.google.com**

[image: fonts.google.com]

**fonts.google.com with console**

[image: fonts.google.com with console]

Firefox works fine. All Google fonts are displayed perfectly and I can see fonts on fonts.google.com but I can't figure out why fonts don't display on Google Chrome or Chromium.

**EDIT:** So, I didn't find any solution for this problem but creating a new user under ubuntu doesn't have this problem and all font's display perfectly in the new user's google chrome. That means that I must have had installed or configured something in the past that caused this and since I mostly use Firefox and I didn't really noticed it until now. I can't really track down what I did but for whoever is reading this you can migrate your user to a new one and that'll fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try to turn off AdBlock for this page?

Comment: @Jos I don't block fonts with uBlock Origin but as I mentioned in the post I tested by removing all extensions from chrome but font's still don't display.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the same version of Google Chrome and Ubuntu. Can you try with a new user (in Google Chrome settings) or in incognito mode? By the way, purging and re-installing won't do anything because your browser settings in *~/.config/google-chrome* will not be removed by purging.

Comment: I don't get the JS errors with Chrome 66. It loads 40 fonts.

Comment: @DKBose Ok, so I again purged chrome and also removed ~/.config/google-chrome directory this time and without signing in and installing any extensions the problem still persists on a fresh install. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/c627O90.png)

Comment: Sorry! I'm out of suggestions!

Comment: Experienced the same. In my case it turned out that Chrome extension "Modify Headers for Google Chrome" re-enabled itself and prevented any GoogleFont from being loaded